# Список организаций Яндекс карты

Tags: yandex-geocoding-api

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать [такой список](https://kaliningrad.zoon.ru/restaurants/?search_query_form=1&center%5B%5D=54.71118197744106&center%5B%5D=20.492378812014476&zoom=10) адресов сбоку в Яндекс Картах? Нужны не просто названия и кластеризация, а еще и изображения, анимация при наведении

То есть вопрос в том, можно ли это сделать средствами API, или придется писать кастомное решение поверх карт?

Comment: Как я понимаю, при помощи апи получится кастомизировать тег геометки, а какова ситуация с остальными частями? Был бы очень благодарен за подскази

Answer (score 0, accepted):

API в ответе не отдаёт рейтинг, фотографии и отзывы, поэтому такой список нужно не только самостоятельно верстать, но и использовать для него собственные данные.

В вашем примере за наполнение карты отвечают разработчики сайта - они выбрали объекты, которые хотят отобразить, собрали контент и сверстали панель в своём дизайне. Карта используется там только для наглядной визуализации их собственных объектов.

Comment: Да, по данным понятно (прочел доки), мне просто было интересно, есть ли уже готовые фишечки, наподобие hover-а хотя бы, или в стилях карт готовый класс для сайдбара. Спасибо!

Comment: @Lorer готового нет)